# Anguar 13 Directive not returning initial Route

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-directives

I recently upgraded to Angular 13.x and im fixing a bit of code and this part is not working any more it doesnt throw any kind of error. So i figured it is just not completed in time for the constructor to return anything valid when loading the page.

current-route.directive.ts

```
  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private router: Router) {
    let routeFrom: string
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), pairwise())
      .subscribe((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {
        routeFrom = events[0].urlAfterRedirects.replace('/', '')
      });
  }
});
```

The same code in the app.component.ts is working fine and i get the route where the Application is called.

app.component.ts

```
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if( val instanceof NavigationStart){
        let url = val.url.replace("/","")
        this.DisplayInterface = url === this.Page ? false : true
      }
    });
  }
```

The directive is nested on my Navbar where its supposed to display a marker for the users current route. On the div i call the directive with `dblCurrentRoute="{{item.link}}`

navbar.component.html

```
<nav class="sidebar">
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of list">
        <div class="marker" dblCurrentRoute="{{item.link}}"></div>
        <a [ngClass]="{'small': Collapsed === true}" [routerLink]="item.link">
          <div class="nav-icon" [ngClass]="{'collapsed': Collapsed === true}">
            <i class="{{item.icon}}"></i>
          </div>
          <span *ngIf="!Collapsed">{{item.name}}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried copying the code from the app.component.ts to my directive without any luck.

Comment: This seems like a long shot, but does it make any difference if you change the syntax to `<div class="marker" [dblCurrentRoute]="item.link"></div>`?

Comment: tried it, it has no effect

Comment: The information you provided is quite extensive, but not enough to debug what's the problem(as it has separate component using the same directive). Please try to provide a minimal reproducible [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you debug better.